# PowerShell switch parameter doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, write-host, switch-parameter

I have the following PowerShell function to help me do benchmarks. The idea is that you provide the command and a number and the function will run the code that number of times. After that the function will report the testing result, such as Min, Max and Average time taken.

```
function Measure-MyCommand()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,
        [Parameter()] [int] $Count = 1,
        [Parameter()] [switch] $ShowOutput
    )

    $time_elapsed = @();
    while($Count -ge 1) {
        $timer = New-Object 'Diagnostics.Stopwatch';
        $timer.Start();
        $temp = & $ScriptBlock;
        if($ShowOutput) {
            Write-Output $temp;
        }
        $timer.Stop();
        $time_elapsed += $timer.Elapsed;
        $Count--;
    }

    $stats = $time_elapsed | Measure-Object -Average -Minimum -Maximum -Property Ticks;

    Write-Host "Min: $((New-Object 'System.TimeSpan' $stats.Minimum).TotalMilliseconds) ms";
    Write-Host "Max: $((New-Object 'System.TimeSpan' $stats.Maximum).TotalMilliseconds) ms";
    Write-Host "Avg: $((New-Object 'System.TimeSpan' $stats.Average).TotalMilliseconds) ms";
}
```

The problem is with the `switch` parameter `$ShowOutput`. As I understand, when you provide a switch parameter, its value is true. Otherwise it's false. However it doesn't seem to work. See my testing.

```
PS C:\> Measure-MyCommand -ScriptBlock {Write-Host "f"} -Count 3 -ShowOutput
f
f
f
Min: 0.4935 ms
Max: 0.8392 ms
Avg: 0.6115 ms
PS C:\> Measure-MyCommand -ScriptBlock {Write-Host "f"} -Count 3
f
f
f
Min: 0.4955 ms
Max: 0.8296 ms
Avg: 0.6251 ms
PS C:\>
```

Can anyone help to explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Write-Host` doesn't return the object and is not a part of pipeline stream, instead it sends text directly to console. You can't simply hide `Write-Host` output by writing it to variable, because `Write-Host` writes to console stream which isn't exposed in PowerShell before version 5. What you need is to replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` cmdlet call. Then you get what you expect. This solution is valid for PowerShell 2.0+.

**Update:**

Starting with PowerShell 5, `Write-Host` writes to its dedicated stream and you can handle and redirect this stream somewhere else. See this response for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60353648/3997611.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the specific script block you're passing, not with your `[switch]` parameter declaration (which works fine):

> `{Write-Host "f"}`

By using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host), you're *bypassing* PowerShell's success output stream (which the assignment to variable `$temp` collects) and printing directly to the host<sup>[1]</sup> (the console), so your output *always* prints.

To print to the success output stream, use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), or better yet, use PowerShell's *implicit* output feature:

```
# "f", due not being capture or redirected, is implicitly sent 
# to the success output stream. 
Measure-MyCommand -ScriptBlock { "f" } -Count 3 -ShowOutput
```

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell 5.0 and higher, `Write-Host` now writes to a new stream, the information stream (number `6`), which by default prints to the host. See [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).
Therefore, a `6>` redirection now *does* allow you to capture `Write-Host` output; e.g.: `$temp = Write-Host hi 6>&1`. Note that the type of the objects captured this way is [`System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord).</sup>