# How to concatenate strings from a text file and execute them in Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I have a text file which a list of JSON files.

Using Powershell, I am able to extract these out of the file and then print the filenames out.

However I want to write a command then execute that in a foreach loop,
but the concatenation is proving tricky.

This is my code so far:

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportDERReturn\ImportDERReturn.txt"))
{
  Write-Host 'aws s3 rm  s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/' + $line.Substring(0,16) + '  --profile DER'
}
```

However im getting the following output:

```
aws s3 rm s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/ + RET02022203.json +   --profile DER
```

But what I want is the following:

```
aws s3 rm  s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/RET02022203.json --profile DER
```

How do I get this output?
How do I get my Powershell script to execute this line?

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) to output *data*; it is meant for *to-display output*, and bypasses PowerShell's success output stream (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60353648/45375) for more information).
- To output data, you don't need an explicit output command at all, so the following *by itself* is enough:

  ```
  'aws s3 rm s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/' + $line.Substring(0,16) + ' --profile DER'
  ```

  - If you do want to use an explicit output command to emit data (which is rarely necessary), use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) or its built-in alias, `echo`; in that case you need to enclose your string-concatenation *expression* (using the `+` operator), in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

    ```
    # Note the use of (...) around the concatenation expression.
    echo ('aws s3 rm s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/' + $line.Substring(0,16) + ' --profile DER')
    ```
- As for *executing* your lines: just invoke `aws` *directly* and use either the `(...)` technique or, more simply *string interpolation* via a [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (line breaks with `` ` `` for line continuations are purely for readability):

  ```
  aws s3 rm `
   "s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/$($line.Substring(0,16))" `
   --profile DER
  ```

  - If you first want to *echo* the command, use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (note that here `` ` `` is used to escape the embedded `"` inside `"..."`):

    ```
    $sb = [scriptblock]::Create("s3 rm `"s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/$($line.Substring(0,16))`" --profile DER")
    # Echo
    $sb.ToString()
    # Execute, using &, the call operator.
    & $sb
    ```
  - [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (whose built-in alias is `iex`), offers a slightly simpler alternative, though note that [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), due to potential security risks:

    ```
     $str = "s3 rm `"s3://Derwent-storage-internal/staging/returns/$($line.Substring(0,16))`" --profile DER"
     # Echo
     $str
     # Execute, using iex (Invoke-Expression)
     iex $str
    ```

Comment: Hi guys

thanks for your help on this.

So we are deleting files from AWS s3 bucket. they have all been processed and checked through our system

so we are good to clear them down...and yes i trust the input from the file...so i will run with iex to invoke expression

thanks for your help and have a great weekend!

Comment: On second thought, @ChrisAsi71: Since the script-block approach offers no security benefit over `Invoke-Expression` here, I've added an `Invoke-Expression` solution back to the answer.